# Flutter app running on web failing with error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter-web, flutter-objectbox

I am trying to get my current Flutter app to run on web. I called `flutter create .` but if I try running it in Chrome I get prompted with about 10000 error messages which all look like this:

> Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
> external ffi.Pointer<OBX_id_array> removals;
> ^
>
> ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/objectbox-1.1.0/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox-c.dart:6289:41:
> Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'. Try removing the
> 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.   external
> ffi.Pointer<OBX_sync_change> list;
> ^
>
> ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/objectbox-1.1.0/lib/src/native/bindings/objectbox-c.dart:6292:16:
> Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'. Try removing the
> 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.   external int
> count;
> ^
>
> Failed to compile application.

I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything on this. Does anyone know what this is about and how I can fit this??

Comment: Well I was using moor db, I had to remove import 'package:moor/ffi.dart';    since it support only mobile devices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re-posting [the answer from a GitHub issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/283) here:

You can't build your app for the web with packages that don't support web, which ObjectBox doesn't yet ([there's an issue you can track though](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/185)).

Sometimes you may want to have the dependency in a small part of the code and it's fine if it doesn't work for the web, in that case,  you can use "conditional imports", such as:

```dart
import 'myapp/sources-that-use-objectbox.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'myapp/sources-that-dont-use-objectbox.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had accidentally used the "ffi" library which is not supported by the web. I then removed all the import made of this library in my code and I also removed the library from "pubsec.yaml". It now launches normally.